# Laravel 5.x compresión de recursos

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

¿Cómo puedo configurar Laravel 5.x para la compresión automática de recursos en el servidor, en concreto el HTML, he intentado poniendo en el **.htaccess** del directorio **public/** las directivas:

```
<IfModule deflate_module>
    # Enable compression for the following file types.
    AddOutputFilterByType            \
     DEFLATE                         \
      text/html                    
</IfModule>
```